# How to have persistent session settings in SDDM for each user?

Tags: session, sddm

I use SDDM as session manager in Lubuntu 19.04. By default I got two desktops: Lubuntu and LXQt. I have two users. Each one uses a different desktop session.

However, every time I switch users, the last used desktop session is shown in drop-down list (when in SDDM).

How can I configure SDDM so it remembers that user1 always starts with Lubuntu session and user2 with LXQt?

Right now the user must manually choose the session every time he enters. I believe it should be a matter of selecting the user, writing the password and voilá!

Comment: @dk-bose, thanks! I was just about to edit the edition of Lubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

These settings are located in `/etc/sddm.conf.d/` you should be able to achieve this with some of the settings?

I would try something like the following

```
/etc/sddm.conf.d/persistent_session
------------------------------------
[Users]
RememberLastSession=true
```

for reference: [sddm.conf](https://jlk.fjfi.cvut.cz/arch/manpages/man/sddm.conf.5)

Comment: j-money, it doesn't work. I tried t use both Remember… settings, even deleted Autologin section, and nada.

Comment: @LobaLuna are you restarting sddm? There should be a log somewhere of what is happening, I don't know where sddm stores these, but you may try checking the journal?

Comment: Yes, @j-money. One restart per each Remember setting, and one for both used together. Your idea of checking the journal is correct. Unfortunately, `/var/log/sddm.log` is empty (don't know why)

Comment: Hmmm, you might try asking upstream then? As it looks like you should be doing everything correctly, (Though we may be misintrepeting some of the flags). https://github.com/sddm/sddm

Comment: I already did. Still no answer. Thanks, anyway. I changed to lightdm. It's light enough and with many more configurable and well documented options. This SDDM guys are very busy, I believe…

Comment: @LobaLuna Did you open an issue? They may be busy, but it's still important that you document it so they know about it!

Comment: You are right. I have to do it.